# Use Akka Streams for transferring file over SFTP

Tags: scala, akka, sftp, jsch, akka-stream

I am currently using Jsch library(http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) in my scala-akka code to download some files from a remote SFTP server.
Depending on the size of the file, it is taking about 1-10 minutes to download the file. So, during this duration, one of the threads is blocked till the file download is complete.

I was looking into Akka Streams and wanted to know if it would be a better choice and is it possible to integrate it with existing pure Jsch based SFTP file download code?

Answer (score 4):

Alpakka, which is built on Akka Streams, has an [FTP connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.18/ftp.html) that you can use to connect to a SFTP server. Whether this is a better choice than your current approach, only you can determine, but if you want to interact with an SFTP server using the goodness of Akka Streams, then the aforementioned Alpakka connector is the way to go.

Comment: I want to understand how "the goodness of Akka Streams" is useful here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Alpakka as chunjef suggested however I believe the issue here is the blocked thread. For that, I would recommend using a specific blocking io dispatcher. You can review the Akka docs (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html#problem-blocking-on-default-dispatcher) to see what are the implications and solutions.

I believe you will face the same problem regardless if you use Akka Streams or not.